# How to get install history for Visual Studio Code extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a log or something that leaves a record for when a particular Extension was installed for Visual Studio Code?

I'm trying to debug some settings that may have been altered and I'd like to work my way backwards uninstalling extensions I've added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The installation of extensions is indeed logged in files called `sharedprocess.log`. On Windows, the location is `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\<Timestamp>`. Here's an example:

```
[2018-03-22 02:24:05.264] [sharedprocess] [info] Installing extension: vscode-table-formatter
[2018-03-22 02:24:06.142] [sharedprocess] [info] Downloaded extension: vscode-table-formatter
[2018-03-22 02:24:07.531] [sharedprocess] [info] Extracted extension to C:\Users\<User>\.vscode\extensions\shuworks.vscode-table-formatter-1.2.1: shuworks.vscode-table-formatter-1.2.1
[2018-03-22 02:24:07.565] [sharedprocess] [info] Updated metadata of the extension: shuworks.vscode-table-formatter-1.2.1
[2018-03-22 02:24:07.565] [sharedprocess] [info] Extensions installed successfully: shuworks.vscode-table-formatter
```

However, why not just open `~/.vscode/extensions` in your file explorer and sort by date? That seems much simpler. :)

Comment: This isn't all that helpful because it seems as if extensions are being updated/reinstalled and that the list isn't actually true to when I first installed the extensions. vscode should add an official sort option. Upvote the issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53405